# Spawn a Linux subprocess without leaking FDs

Tags: c, linux, thread-safety, child-process

I'm working on a library of shell utilities for Swift, and at the core of it is the need to spawn a subprocess.

For Linux, I came up with the following function to do the low-level work.

Requirements that led to this ugliness:

- it can remap FDs arbitrarily (like bash)
- it must work in a library (can't assume files were opened with `O_CLOEXEC`)
- it must work in a multithreaded environment (no doing anything fun after fork)
- it can't leak any resources (FDs especially were a pain here)
- it reports back **any** failures as an error

I'm most interested in writing a bullet-proof piece of code, and any suggestions would be appreciated.

This should be entirely self-contained, but here's the [code in context](https://github.com/cobbal/swsh/blob/linux/Sources/linuxSpawn/linux-spawn.c).

```
/// spawn a process in a similar manner to posix_spawn using options
/// POSIX_SPAWN_CLOEXEC_DEFAULT and POSIX_SPAWN_START_SUSPENDED, neither of
/// which are available on linux.
///  - Parameter command: name of executable. Either the path to an executable,
///    or will be looked up in PATH. (Passed directly to `execvpe`)
///  - Parameter argv: null terminated list of arguments to pass to command.
///    (Passed directly to `execvpe`)
///  - Parameter envp: null terminated list of all environment variables to pass
///    to command. (Passed directly to `execvpe`)
///  - Parameter fdMap: a list of mappings from parent FDs to be inherited by child
///    FDs. Any FD not listed as a dst will be closed for the child. The list
///    must be -1 terminated, and in the format:
///    `{ src_0, dst_0, src_1, dst_1, ..., src_n, dst_n, -1 }`
///  - Returns: 0 if successful, an error code if an operation failed.
///  - Parameter child_pid_out: non-null, pid of child process will be written
///    to this pointer if successful.
int spawn(
    const char *command,
    char *const argv[],
    char *const envp[],
    int32_t *const fdMap,
    pid_t *child_pid_out
) {
    // First, create a table for fast lookup if an FD is a source and/or a
    // destination for dup
    int fdlimit = (int)sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
    const int SRC = 1;
    const int DST = 2;
    uint8_t mentionedFds[fdlimit];
    bzero(mentionedFds, sizeof(mentionedFds));
    for (int32_t *p = fdMap; *p != -1; p += 2) {
        mentionedFds[p[0]] |= SRC;
        mentionedFds[p[1]] |= DST;
    }

    int pid;
    int pipeFds[2];
    // create a pipe so that the child can report to the parent on failure. If
    // it's closed silently, it's a successful exec. If not, it will send an
    // error code.
    if (pipe2(pipeFds, O_CLOEXEC) != 0) {
        return errno;
    }

    if (!(pid = fork())) {
        // In child process. Prepare state for exec.

        // Find an FD to store our pipe in that won't interfere with fdMap
        int writePipe = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < fdlimit; i++) {
            if (!mentionedFds[i]) {
                if (i == pipeFds[i]) {
                    // pipe picked a good fd, nothing to do
                    writePipe = i;
                } else if ((writePipe = dup3(pipeFds[1], i, O_CLOEXEC)) < 0) {
                    goto err;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (writePipe < 0) {
            // All file descriptors seem to be in use, not one to spare for some
            // bookkeeping :(
            errno = EMFILE;
            goto err;
        }
        // do the actual fd remapping
        for (int32_t *p = fdMap; *p != -1; p += 2) {
            if (dup2(p[0], p[1]) < 0) {
                goto err;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < fdlimit; i++) {
            // close all the FDs we don't need, even ones that aren't open
            // (faster than checking which ones are open I read somewhere on the
            // internet)
            if (!(mentionedFds[i] & DST) && i != writePipe) {
                close(i);
            }
        }
        // All good! If this returns, exec failed with an error.
        execvpe(command, argv, envp);
      err:;
        int err = errno;
        write(writePipe, &err, sizeof(err));
        exit(err);
    }
    // parent code

    // close our copy of the pipe's write end
    close(pipeFds[1]);
    int ret = 0;
    if (pid < 0) {
        // fork failed
        ret = pid;
    } else if (read(pipeFds[0], &ret, sizeof(ret)) == 0) {
        // pipe was closed silently, fork and exec succeeded
        *child_pid_out = pid;
    }
    close(pipeFds[0]);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Put `const` in the right place

You write `int32_t *const fdMap`, which means the pointer `fdMap` is constant, but it allows writes to the values inside the map. You probably meant that you want the contents of `fdMap` to be read-only, so you have to write instead:

```
const int32_t *fdMap
```

However, if you want you can make both the pointer and the values pointed to constant:

```
const int32_t *const fdMap
```

The same goes for `argv` and `envp`.

## Filedescriptors are `int`s

They are not `int32_t`s. So write:

```
const int *fdMap
```

## Avoid unnecessary casts

Calls to `sysconf()` return a `long`, not an `int`, so store the result in a variable of type `long`:

```
long fdlimit = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
```

And indeed, when you are looping over all possible filedescriptors, write `for (long i = 0; i < fdlimit; i++)`.

## Avoid allocating potentially large arrays on the stack

The maximum number of open files can be very large. The stack size your program gets is not unlimited. So a declaration like:

```
uint8_t mentionedFds[fdlimit];
```

Can be larger than would fit in your stack. It is best to allocate memory on the heap for this:

```
uint8_t *mentionedFds = calloc(fdlimit, sizeof(*mentionedFds));
```

## Consider passing `fdMap` in a more structured way

The way you pass `fdMap` is a bit hackish. Since you actually pass an array of filedescriptor *pairs*, make this explicit, along with the size of that array:

```
struct fd_pair {
    int src;
    int dst;
};
...
int spawn(..., const struct fd_pair *fdMap, size_t fdMap_size, ...)
```

Then later on, read the map like so:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < fdMap_size; i++) {
    mentionedFds[fdMap[i].src] |= SRC;
    mentionedFds[fdMap[i].dst] |= DST;
}
```

## Make constants the right type

Since `SRC` and `DST` are used to fill in `mentionedFds`, make sure they have the same type as the elements of the latter. You can also make them `static`:

```
static const uint8_t SRC = 1;
static const uint8_t DST = 2;
```